# Adding childs to list of parents with jquery /mvc2

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, parent-child

I have a table of products on my page, each product has zero or more colors, the colors are shown as a list beneath the product. After the colors I have a button to add a color. The button will do an ajax call with the parent product id to a controller which will return a JSON object with color information. My problem is where to store the product id in the DOM, should I put it in a hidden field and use jquery in the click event of the "add color" to get to it? What is the best way to do this?

TIA,

John

**EDIT**: The page is initially rendered on the server so I don't want to use jquery to add the id's to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would be to put it in an anchor tag's rel attribute. Or you can use the metadata plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata. It's capable of getting "data-something" attributes from an element. And the "data-something" attribute is valid for HTML 5 ([more info](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)).

So you can have your html look like:

```
<tr data-productid="123"><td>...</td></tr>
```

And on a click event:

```
var productId = $('tr-selector-here').metadata().productid;
```